# Combining states in continuous-time Markov chain

Tags: probability

I have a continuous-time Markov chain with Q-matrix\begin{pmatrix}
-\mu-\lambda & \lambda & \mu \\
\lambda & -\mu-\lambda & \mu \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} and I want to find $P(X_t=3|X_0=1)$. I want to do this by combining states $1$ and $2$ into a single state. If I do this am I right in saying that the new Q-matrix is \begin{pmatrix}
-\mu & \mu \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} to then get $P(X_t=3|X_0=1)=1-e^{-\mu t}$?